How can I prevent / correct Excel groups of checkboxes size and position changing after reopening the file?
I use grouped checkboxes (formular controls) in Excel sheets for the purpose of diagnosis. One sheet is uses as template and I copy the sheet as I need a new diagnosis with a macro.
There is a known bug in Excel, that causes changes of size and position of objects, like images or control elements. (I know all the properties functions for locking sizes,... - it will not avoid the bug changing the sizes)
I can correct sizes of images easily after the sheet is copied also with a macro.
But: at groups of checkboxes I have no solution, because within the new sheet copy the groups gets also new group names, which I can't use with a macro later for repositioning.
I would be extremly grateful, if you could help me out.
Any idea to give the checkbox groups unique names, like you could to with images oder an idea to find and identify the groups after copy from the template sheet would be great.
update: what I could find out so far: if I rename each group of checkboxes manually, the group name doesn't change after copy to a new sheet. So I have a workaround, as long as I reposition each group with a macro like this, so size and position are fixed to the specific cell.
Code for resizing
Sub Checkbox_Group_Meridiane()
Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim oCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set oShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chkbox_Meridiane")
    Set oCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B36")
    oShape.Top = oCell.Top + 5
    oShape.Left = oCell.Left + 5
    oShape.Width = 540
    oShape.Height = 65
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chkbox_Meridiane")).Select
    HOEHE = Selection.ShapeRange.Height
    Breite = Selection.ShapeRange.Width
    oShape.Width = Breite
    oShape.Height = HOEHE
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 65   ' Bugfix to get the wright size
    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = HOEHE    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


I have not heard of the bug you describe in Excel, could you post some code that shows the problem?

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

you can find comments on that issue here:
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1272891-active-x-checkboxes-keep-resizing.html

The link in the comment above says that the issue is only with ActiveX checkboxes, Forms checkboxes are OK. Which one are you using OP?

The problem is the same - I use Forms checkboxes.
